# Samba authenticate users against Windows Domain Controller (without /etc/nsswitch.conf)

Tags: samba, authentication, samba4

I want to setup a samba server that offers shares. The only thing it should do is:

1. Authenticate access to the shares against an existing windows domain controller.

The things I want to avoid is:

1. Having to add `winbind` to `/etc/nsswitch.conf`
2. Do not have the AD users on my local systems (`getent passwd` should not show the AD users).

I really only want to have the authentication parsed of to the windows server itself.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Join the Linux server to the domain using `realmd`/`sssd`. It will automatically configure `nsswitch`, `pam` and whatever is necessary.
Then restrict the local (`ssh`) login to deny domain users from logging in to your Linux server.

But if you really don't want `getent` to show the users, maybe you can use `ldap` instead of `sssd`.